# Ipa - entitlistments problems

Tags: ios, xcode, configuration, ipa, ios-provisioning

We have received a Ipa file from a developer, and want to resign it with our own distribution certificate.
That part is quite easy from the terminal.

I tried to install the app afterwards through apple configurator 2, but can see on the device log that "the executable was signed with invalid entitlements"

If I check the mobile provisioning I can see it has been certified with my company ID that I did. But checking the app entitlements, it still stand with the external companies info

Anyone have a clue how to change this

Comment: Anyone has an idea how to add these entitlements to the re-signed Ipa file ?

Answer (score 0):

Add `--entitlements` to your re-sign ipa command to sign with entitlements.

`codesign -f -s "iPhone Distribution: Developer (ABCDEFGHIJ)" --entitlements entitlements.plist YourApp/YourApp.app`

You can find the entitlements from your app and modify it.

```
...
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>application-identifier</key>
    <string>ABCDEFGHIJ.com.yourapp</string>
    <key>aps-environment</key>
    <string>production</string>
    <key>get-task-allow</key>
    <false/>
</dict>
</plist>
```